# Can not get Instagram Access Token using request module in node

Tags: node.js, oauth, request, instagram, instagram-api

I'm building a simple node app using request and Instagram api and I'm trying to make a call for the instagram access token in the final step of the oauth process. For some reason Instagam's api is responding with a 400 saying my client_id is not specified when it is clearly specified in my request body. Here is a link to instagram's oauth process: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

HERE IS MY REQUEST CODE:

```
var options = {
  url: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
  method: 'POST',
  oauth: {
    "client_id": process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    "client_secret": process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
  },
  json: {
    "client_id": process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    "client_secret": process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    "grant_type" : "authorization_code",
    "code" : response.req.query.code,
    "redirect_uri" : 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/redirect'
  }
};

request(options, function ( error, response ) {
  if(error) { console.log(error); }
  else { console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); }
});
```

HERE IS THE RESPONSE:

```
{"statusCode":400,"body":{"code":400,"error_type":"OAuthException","error_messag
e":"You must provide a client_id"},"headers":{"content-language":"en","expires":
"Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT","vary":"Cookie, Accept-Language","pragma":"no-ca
che","cache-control":"private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate","date":"Wed,
 27 Apr 2016 05:37:03 GMT","content-type":"application/json","set-cookie":["csrf
 token=456dc5df05f5b0aad286723004e395fe; expires=Wed, 26-Apr-2017 05:37:03 GMT; M
ax-Age=31449600; Path=/","mid=VyBP_wAEAAGhT9YCRDGVBM6tksC7; expires=Tue, 22-Apr-
2036 05:37:03 GMT; Max-Age=630720000; Path=/"],"connection":"close","content-len
gth":"94"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"https:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"hos
t":"api.instagram.com","port":443,"hostname":"api.instagram.com","hash":null,"se
arch":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/oauth/access_token","path":"/oauth/access_t
oken","href":"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"},"method":"POST","he
aders":{"accept":"application/json","content-   type":"application/json","content-l
ength":223,"Authorization":"OAuth oauth_client_id=\"[THE ACUAL RESPONSE       DISPLAYS ID HERE]\",oauth_client_secret=\"[THE ACTUAL RESPONSE DISPLYS SECRET     HERE]\",oauth_nonce=\"cc
173578667148d1bdf341926b9e2cd0\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_time
stamp=\"1461735413\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"zeQxrYVNSsveztczszW
FiY3jGz8%3D\""}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the environment variable process.env.CLIENT_ID doesnt have value.
Try using hard coded strings instead of process.env.CLIENT_ID and process.env.CLIENT_SECRET

Comment: No the environment variables log as strings of my id and secret so they are definitely not undefined. Could it be the way I'm specifying them in the request body?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this also for days with other apis. But this works quitly for all api oAuth 2 requests.

```
request.post({url:'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', form: {
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost/dashboard',
    client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    client_secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    code: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
}
}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* ... */ 
console.log('err: ' + err)
console.log('body: ' + body)
})
```

I use as redirect url also when register the app http://localhost/dashboard
Don´t use only http://localhost because if you use XAMPP then you will get always redirected to http://localhost/dashboard and this means your can´t get the code from
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code